# Meteor publish - subscribe user profile

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to publish a user profile. I have the following publish function in publish.js:

```
Meteor.publish("singleProfile", function ( profileId ) {
  check(profileId, String);
  return Meteor.users.find(profileId, { fields: { _id: 1, services: 1, profile: 1 }});
});
```

This is my route in router.js:

```
Router.route('/profile/:_id', {
    name:           'profilePage',
    template:       'appProfile',
    onBeforeAction: function() {
      var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
      if(currentUser) {
        this.next();
      } else {
        this.render("signin");
      }
    },
    waitOn: function() {
      this.response = Meteor.subscribe('singleProfile', this.params._id);
      return this.response;
    },
    action: function() {
      this.render('appProfile');
    }
  });
```

Question is, how do I access the profile details in the appProfile template? Do I need a template helper defined? Or do I need to modify this code?

Comment: Ok, it looks like that the helper is still required and I have to run find on the MiniCollection, where the publish happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template helper for this:

```
Template.appProfile.helpers({
    users() {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    }
});
```

Then in your template:

```
...
{{#each users}}
    {{profile.myProperty}} <!-- Renders the myProperty field of the profile. -->
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Correct, I eventually figured it out. My confusion was that why do I have to do Meteor.users.find() again in the helper? After reading the documentation about subscription I figured out that subscriptions are held in MiniMongo Collections in the browser and that Meteor.users.find() in the helper searches that MiniMongo collection not the backend.